# retrieving e-mail from user after submission through Direct Url OAuth Dialog?

Tags: facebook, url, redirect, oauth, dialog

I am using the Link

```
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
scope=email,user_birthday&
client_id=289912184369824&
redirect_uri=http://takeinsocialmedia.com&
response_type=token`
```

To request the user e-mail and birthday on our landing page. this link will be connected to a normal html button to accept user information quicker then then typing it in. How do i access the e-mail information and birthday information?

please understand that I am not a coder and do not have full knowledge of how to use API.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the access token a call to `/me/?fields=birthday,email` will return the two fields you want.

if you're not using any of the SDKs for some reason, you can manually go to `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday,email&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}` to get the values